Is there another loss that can replace seq2seq.sequence_loss in tensorflow
I am running a CVAE for text generation. I am using tensorflow > 2.0.
The problem is that for my loss I use the seq2seq.sequence_loss. I tried to update the tensorflow v1 to v2 since the code was released 6 years ago.
Here below a snippet of my code:
class CustomVariationalLayer(Layer):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        self.is_placeholder = True
        super(CustomVariationalLayer, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.target_weights = tf.constant(np.ones((batch_size, max_len)), tf.float32)

def vae_loss(self, x, x_decoded_mean):
    labels = tf.cast(x, tf.int32)
    xent_loss = K.sum(tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(x_decoded_mean, labels, 
                                                 weights=self.target_weights,
                                                 average_across_timesteps=False,
                                                 average_across_batch=False), axis=-1)#,
                                                 #softmax_loss_function=softmax_loss_f), axis=-1)#,
    kl_loss = - 0.5 * K.sum(1 + z_log_var - K.square(z_mean) - K.exp(z_log_var), axis=-1)
    xent_loss = K.mean(xent_loss)
    kl_loss = K.mean(kl_loss)
    return K.mean(xent_loss + kl_weight * kl_loss)

And I have this error after running the script:
File "/dm4i/work/VAE-testbyme/Textvae_v2.py", line 193, in call  *
loss = self.vae_loss(x, x_decoded_mean)
File "/dm4i/work/VAE-testbyme/Textvae_v2.py", line 179, in vae_loss  *
xent_loss = K.sum(tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss(x_decoded_mean, labels,
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'

Any hints? or tips?
Thanks a lot

One possibility is to use tfa.seq2seq.sequence_loss, which is basically a port of tf.contrib.seq2seq.sequence_loss to TensorFlow 2. You can get it by installing the TensorFlow Addons package. It's not ideal though, as Tensorflow Addons (tfa) is deprecated as well and will stop receiving any maintenance after May 2024.
